# In Swift, how can I check that a user is no longer touching the screen after touchesMoved is triggered?

Tags: swift, touchesmoved

I need to know that a user started to touch the screen and then know when he is not touching it anymore.

With *touchesBegan* and *touchesEnded* I can get such information. However, if the user is swiping his fingers, then I know he started doing it with *touchesMoved*. 
However I am not able to check when he is no longer touching the screen.
Basically , *touchesEnded* will not fire after the user stopped swipping.
Any ideas?

Example of my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


    if let touch = touches.first {
    print("Finger touched!")
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {

        print("Finger is swipping!")

    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {

        print("finger is not touching.") //this will not fire if finger stopped swipping

    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
}
```

Comment: You will get either `touchesEnded(_:,withEvent:)` or `touchesCancelled(_:,withEvent:)` for every touch. Are you overriding `touchesCancelled(_:,withEvent:)`?

Comment: Why are you calling `super.touchesBegan` on all 3 methods?

Comment: Hi. I am trying to follow your suggestion using 'code' override  func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event);
  
    } but I get the error: Method does not overide any method from its superclass

Comment: It was just a test...

Answer (score 3):

working in Swift 3

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.first != nil {
        print("Finger touched!")
    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.first != nil {
        print("finger is not touching.")  
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.first != nil {
        print("Touch Move")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said:

```
print("finger is not touching.") //this will not fire if finger stopped swipping
```

You're right that it will not fire if the finger stopped *moving*. But it *will* fire if the finger leaves the screen (stops touching), which is what you asked about ("no longer touching the screen").

Answer (score 1):

`touchesBegan:withEvent:` always gets called for one or more fingers when they touch the screen that are considered part of the same touch event.  `touchesMoved:withEvent:` gets fired when one or more fingers in the event move.  `touchesEnded:withEvent:` get fired when one or more of the fingers in the touch event are removed from the screen.  Lastly, `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` is called if the whole event is invalidated (i.e., cancelled).

For a given event you will always receive one or more calls to `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, probably many calls to `touchesMoved:withEvent`, and then either one or more calls to `touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`

A few things to consider here:

1. You should always implement all four of these methods, even if you do nothing, to prevent partial events from going up the responder chain (which is what the super implementation does).
2. You should not call super if you are handling the events.
3. If you do call super because you want to dispatch the events up the responder chain, you must call the correct super method (you are calling `touchesBegan:withEvent:` on super in your `touchesMoved:withEvent` implementation

To answer your question specifically, you implement `touchesEnded:withEvent` to know when the user has stopped touching the screen with one or more touches that are part of the event.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very newbie in this. But in the code example I gave, the message "finger is not touching." will never be shown, in case the user swipped the screen. However it will be shown IF the user pressed down and then up without swipping.

Comment: Try removing the calls to super from your implementations.  They should not be there.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` or `UIPanGestureRecongizer`?  It's rare that you really need to write your own gesture handling code these days.

Comment: Thank you Charles A. That sorted the issue! :)

Comment: It's funny, if you want to check if a user is panning a mapView, then the touchesEnded:withEvent won't fire after swiping. Basically, what I need to do, is to prevent a certain function to be executed while a user is dragging a mapView. Until now, I could not find a working solution.